# Copying files to new directory in SBT

Tags: sbt

How do I copy files contained within a PathFinder to a new directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Answered on the sbt mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/simple-build-tool/mccann/simple-build-tool/1H399ySe93U/YD8wT0q0LUEJ):

```
def copy(finder: PathFinder, dst: File) = {
  IO.copy(finder.get map {f => (f, dst / f.getName)})
}
```