# Re-using settings in multi-project build with SBT

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

am using Play! 2.0 with and I have a question about the build system.  I have an aggregate of multiple projects, and I have a shared module which contains static files and some .less files which gets compiled into a css.

How can I copy the static files as well as the output of the compiled stylesheets into other projects?  I tried to understand by myself but it appears that, while I can apply easily to a project a setting, I can't retrieve from another project that setting.

I have looked into the Play! 2.0 keys

```
val playAssetsDirectories = SettingKey[Seq[File]]("play-assets-directories")

val incrementalAssetsCompilation = SettingKey[Boolean]("play-incremental-assets-compilation")

val playExternalAssets = SettingKey[Seq[(File, File => PathFinder, String)]]("play-external-assets")
```

But I have no idea on how to use this information to modify my build file.

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "Website"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    val common = PlayProject(
        appName + "-common", appVersion, path = file("modules/common"),mainLang=SCALA,
    lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory(_ / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "bootstrap.less")
    )



    val website = PlayProject(
        appName + "-website", appVersion, path = file("modules/website"),mainLang=SCALA,

    ).dependsOn(common)

    val adminArea = PlayProject(
        appName + "-admin", appVersion, path = file("modules/admin"),mainLang=SCALA,

    ).dependsOn(common)

    val main = PlayProject(
        appName, appVersion,appDependencies,mainLang=SCALA
    ).dependsOn(
        website, adminArea
    )
}
```

What I basically would like to say it's:

```
website.playExternalAssets += common.playAssetsDirectory(IncludingCompiled)
```

but this is clearly not legal.

I have actually understood a little bit more, and the following code seems almost right:

```
  val website = PlayProject(
        appName + "-website", appVersion, path = file("modules/website"),mainLang=SCALA

    ).dependsOn(common).settings(playExternalAssets <<= common.playAssetsDirectory(IncludingCompile))
```

Except that common.playAssetsDirectory does not work:

```
[info] Loading project definition from G:\project1\project [error] G:\project1\project\Build.scala:26: value playAssetsDirectory is not a member of sbt.Project [error]         ).dependsOn(common).settings(playExternalAssets <<= common.playA ssetsDirectory(IncludingCompile)) [error]                              ^ [error] one error found [error] {file:/G:/project1/project/}default-436781/compile:compile: Compilati on failed
```

It looks like the problem here is that keys are constant vals and not properties of a Project. In fact, the keys are constant global values defined in PlayKeys, so I would actually need to specify the scope but I do not know how

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: You quoted the error message instead of pasting it as code. That destroyed the position of the `^` carret. At a guess, remove `common.`.

Comment: This does not work because as I explained the keys must be scoped... :(

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the subject misled me. You don't want to share settings, you want to copy stuff. You can depend on other projects, which will make their JAR available to you -- resources can then be retrieved with getResource.

AFAIK, you cannot depend on anything outside a project's root -- that includes files on other projects.

From that point on, you'll need a task. You could have a task uncompress data from the jar and copy it to the proper places.

You may also look into [tasks that copy things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713483/copying-files-to-new-directory-in-sbt), which might provide an alternative.

Comment: How can I use the task ? Do you have a more detailed guide?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Like any other task -- every action in SBT is either a task or a command, and all of the stuff that is depended on by other stuff is a task. Look at the SBT wiki for more information, but I'm figuring you'd make compile dependent on the task you created, so that it sees the files that you are copying.